# Run multiple projects in debug mode from the command line in Visual Studio

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2022

Our program has multiple parts (Frontend npm, Backend and multiple executables in one solution). It's tedious to always open all these and run them manually so I'm trying to make a bat script to run them all for me. This includes building and running the backend and the executables **in debug mode**. The executables reside in a single solution but it's made up of multiple projects that need to run simultaneously. It is configured in to start all the needed projects when running the  solution

I also want to start the three solutions concurrently so the script is not waiting for each of them to start up but starts them at the same time.

I've looked up how to use [Visual Studio from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022).

- I've tried using the /run switch at first but this only builds and runs the program without debugging which is not the desired outcome for me.
- I've tried seeing if /? has more info than the online documentation but it also didn't list an option that would be good for me.
- I wanted to use /build option then use /debugexe but then I would have to run it for all my executables and I want all projects to run from one debugging session.

I've also found various stackoverflow questions about running visual studio from the command line but none of them seemed to ask for what I need in this scenario.

This is my .bat so far

```
@echo off

set "VS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

set "PROGRAM_FOLDER=C:\Dev\Repos\Program"
set "PROGRAM_SOLUTION=Program.sln"

set "BACKEND_FOLDER=C:\Dev\Repos\web-backend"
set "BACKEND_SOLUTION=Web-Backend.sln"

set "FRONTEND_FOLDER=C:\Dev\Repos\web-frontend"


@REM EXECUTION ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@REM Programs
echo Opening Programs solution folder
cd /d "%PROGRAM_FOLDER%"

echo Build and run solution
"%VS_PATH%" /run "%PROGRAM_SOLUTION%"

@REM Backend
echo Opening Backend solution folder
cd /d "%BACKEND_FOLDER%"

echo Build and run solution
"%VS_PATH%" /run "%BACKEND_SOLUTION%"

@REM Frontend
echo Opening Frontend folder
cd /d "%FRONTEND_FOLDER%"

echo Starting frontend
npm start
```

Comment: We typically `start` executables and `call` batch files. `start` is to launch them outside of the `cmd` console. So each would start after each other and not have to wait for them to complete before starting the next process. Also. `Start "" "path\program.exe"` .... with the empty comment double quotes after start

Comment: You say that everything is all in one Solution? In which case, is there a reason you can't use the normal Visual Studio functionality for multiple startup projects? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022

Comment: Yep this is the way it's set up right now. When I use the /run switch it works fine, the problem is I also want to debug.

Answer (score -2):

If you need that debugger to be called while starting the processes, I suggest a different approach over the batch script. You probably want to have only a single debugging session for all processes instead of individual sessions for each one. In that case, you might be better off creating a simple launcher application that spawns child processes. It would do the same job as the batch script, but it will be a lot easier to attach a debugger to it. (EDIT: ...since it can track the PID of those processes.)

Looks like you already have working a solution to run your applications without debugger... There is an extension that will allow you to debug to multiple processes: https://github.com/karpach/debug-attach-manager